# Highcharts print formatting issues

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get this chart to print (see code in jsfiddle below). There are a lot of series and when printing the chart all the series get on top of the graph.. Is there a way to avoid this?  or a better way to do it? I tried to add more margin-bottom but that affects the other many graphs I have.. Is there a solution without adding margin-bottom? Thanks!

[image]

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
    useUTC: false
  },
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: [{
          text: 'PRINT CHART',
          onclick: function() {
            this.print();
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
});
Highcharts.chart('basicLineEnvironmentGD', {
  chart: {
    type: '',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var label = this.renderer.label("")
          .css({
            width: '600px',
            fontSize: '1em',
            color: '#414042'
          })
          .attr({
            'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'r': 2,
            'padding': 5
          })
          .add();
        label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
          align: 'center',
          x: 20,
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          y: 0
        }), null, 'spacingBox');
      }
    },
    marginBottom: 160
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Decoupled Growth Levels and Environmental Impact - index (1991 =1)',
    style: {
      fontSize: '2.5em'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'CEPI Statistics - Status as of 2015'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015
    ]
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    y: -55
  },
  series: [{
    color: '#8cc640',
    name: 'Production of Market Pulp and Paper',
    data: [
      1.00, 1.03, 1.06, 1.08, 1.17, 1.19, 1.17, 1.27, 1.30, 1.34, 1.41, 1.38, 1.42, 1.50, 1.56, 1.57, 1.63, 1.63, 1.57, 1.40, 1.52, 1.50, 1.48, 1.47, 1.46, 1.46,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#26b6cc',
    name: 'Total Primary Energy Consumption',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.98, 0.96, 0.97, 0.94, 0.95, 0.97, 0.93, 0.91, 0.90, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.88, 0.87, 0.84, 0.86, 0.85, 0.84, 0.87, 0.87, 0.83, 0.82, 0.81, 0.79, 0.80,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#009347',
    name: 'Biomass Utilisation',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.98, 0.96, 1.00, 0.98, 0.99, 0.98, 0.98, 0.98, 0.99, 0.97, 0.98, 1.00, 0.99, 0.98, 0.96, 0.98, 0.99, 1.00, 1.05, 1.03, 1.03, 1.05, 1.05, 1.01, 1.04,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#005eb8',
    name: 'Electricity Consumption',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.96, 0.95, 0.96, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.92, 0.92, 0.90, 0.90, 0.89, 0.87, 0.85, 0.83, 0.86, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.83, 0.81, 0.80, 0.79, 0.79,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#6cbd56',
    name: 'CO2',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.95, 0.94, 0.91, 0.89, 0.88, 0.91, 0.83, 0.81, 0.79, 0.75, 0.75, 0.74, 0.73, 0.68, 0.68, 0.65, 0.63, 0.63, 0.64, 0.62, 0.60, 0.58, 0.57, 0.54, 0.54,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#AEADB3',
    name: 'NOX',
    data: [
      1.00, 1.00, 0.96, 0.94, 0.89, 0.85, 0.84, 0.79, 0.74, 0.73, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71, 0.71, 0.69, 0.64, 0.66, 0.63, 0.63, 0.66, 0.65, 0.65, 0.60, 0.61, 0.56, 0.56,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#2f7cba',
    name: 'Water Intake',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.93, 0.89, 0.83, 0.77, 0.75, 0.73, 0.68, 0.65, 0.64, 0.60, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 0.63, 0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 0.55, 0.58, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#51a332',
    name: 'COD',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.88, 0.73, 0.63, 0.55, 0.53, 0.48, 0.44, 0.40, 0.35, 0.34, 0.33, 0.31, 0.30, 0.28, 0.25, 0.25, 0.24, 0.23, 0.24, 0.24, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.21, 0.21,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#87868A',
    name: 'SO2',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.82, 0.74, 0.63, 0.55, 0.49, 0.46, 0.40, 0.34, 0.29, 0.25, 0.25, 0.24, 0.21, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.19, 0.17, 0.17, 0.15, 0.13, 0.11, 0.12, 0.09, 0.10,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#00a0b0',
    name: 'BOD',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.88, 0.74, 0.66, 0.55, 0.54, 0.46, 0.44, 0.40, 0.36, 0.32, 0.31, 0.30, 0.27, 0.24, 0.20, 0.19, 0.18, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.16, 0.16, 0.15, 0.14,
    ]
  }, {
    color: '#6aa242',
    name: 'AOX',
    data: [
      1.00, 0.75, 0.47, 0.29, 0.20, 0.16, 0.12, 0.11, 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04,
    ]
  }],
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="mtGraph" id="basicLineEnvironmentGD"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes! very acceptable.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [`alignColumns`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.alignColumns) to `false`.

> If the layout is horizontal and the legend items span over two lines or more, whether to align the items into vertical columns. Setting this to false makes room for more items, but will look more messy.

Set like this:

```
legend: {
  alignColumns: false,
  ...
},
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/dt9qqhqg/

Comment: Thanks! I guess for this amount of series we will compromise a bit on how neat it look.